# Paypal Integration for Multiple Receiver and one Sender

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to integrate paypal in website for Paying salary to many employee in a company. How can we do it using php (laravel). For single receiver and multiple payer I used paypal checkout. 
But I have no idea how to do for one payer and multiple reciever. 
**Payer** : website admin(company manager)
**receiver** : employee for company

Comment: Please describe some code you have done

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement paypal payments api, then you can initiate payments from backend using api's

Comment: How to do it? How to do it

Comment: Are you familiar with using api in php? if not then consider learning that.. and you should go forward using paypal's api

Comment: Yes i am familiar with using api in php for checkout and recurring payment but i don't know how to solve this condition.

Comment: Thank you shubham sakharkar